# Changing only certain y value with an input slider

Tags: r, dplyr, ggvis

I want to show with an interactive `ggvis` plot the impact of outliers on the estimated OLS regression line. For this I want a slider which updates only one y value of my dataframe e.g `df$y[10] + 1`, `df$y[10] + 2` and so on. How can I achieve this?

Some data to play arround with:

```
set.seed(123)
x     <- sort(runif(15, min = 30, max = 70 ))
y     <- rnorm(15 , mean = 200, sd = 50)
df    <- data.frame(x, y)
```

My current static ggvis code:

```
Library(ggvis)
df %>% 
ggvis(x = ~x, y = ~y)  %>%
layer_points() %>%
layer_model_predictions(model  = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to combine the `dplyr` functionality with ggvis.
The following link describes how it works:

[dplyr verbs for ggvis](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/ggvis/man/dplyr-ggvis.html)

> Applying a dplyr verb to a ggvis object creates a reactive
>   transformation: whenever the underlying data changes the
>   transformation will be recomputed.

With that I ended up using mutate with a self written function `outlier`. 
The important point is to wrap the reactive slider input in `eval()`. I am sure there still is potential for improvement but this might be a good starting point.

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
x     <- sort(runif(15, min = 30, max = 70 ))
y     <- rnorm(15 , mean = 200, sd = 50)
df    <- data.frame(y, x)

v       <- input_slider(0, 250, value = 0, step = 25, animate = TRUE)
outlier <- function(y, v) y + c(rep(0, 14), v)

df %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~x, y = ~y)  %>% 
  mutate(y = outlier(y, eval(v))) %>% 
  layer_points() %>%
  layer_model_predictions(model  = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```